# Symfony 2 An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar 404

Tags: symfony

Im basically having the same issue as:

[Symfony 2 - An error occurred while loading the web debug toolbar (404: Not Found)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236623/symfony-2-an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-web-debug-toolbar-404-not-found)

Although that solution doesn't work for me.

None of my routes apart from / are working, and when I do go to '/' I get the above error.

running `php app/console router:debug` shows all my routes being listed fine, but actually visiting them results in a 404.

My .htaccess is

```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteRule ^app_dev.php(/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$2 [R=301,L]    ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule .? - [L]
RewriteRule .? %{ENV:BASE}/app_dev.php [L]        ##### this is the part that you should tweak, have the .htaccess point the request to app_dev.php, since the routing.yml is empty initially
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    # When mod_rewrite is not available, we instruct a temporary redirect of
    # the startpage to the front controller explicitly so that the website
    # and the generated links can still be used.
    RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /app.php/
    # RedirectTemp cannot be used instead
</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a server config issue.

Mod rewrite was installed and enabled, so it wasn't that. A fresh LAMP install solved it though.