# Symfony error 404 toolbar not found and subdirectories

Tags: php, symfony, nginx

After searching on Stackoverflow about this question, I read about different possible solutions and different references to different links. I am not a pro at working with Symfony, in fact, I am a total beginner and I am not really well aware of which file saves what kind of data etc. So to ask my question:
What should I do in order for my Symfony application to work fine?

I used Vagrant to SSH into my virtual Ubuntu system and this is an error log I found that actually keeps an error, however it is from january, meaning that this log does not log the error I am still experiencing. Does anyone know which error log I should look for so I can share it here and help you out identifying my problem by doing so?

```
[01:39 PM]-[vagrant@local]-[/var/log/nginx] B
B$ dir
_.access.log    _.error.log.1                     nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.error.log
access.log      error.log.1                       nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.error.log.1
_.access.log.1  nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.access.log       project_access.log
_.error.log     nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.access.log.1     project_access.log.1
error.log       nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.access.log.2.gz  project_error.log

[01:40 PM]-[vagrant@local]-[/var/log/nginx] B
B$ tail -1 nxv_6hujsloyp5ug.error.log.1
2016/01/29 13:58:06 [error] 16933#0: *40 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.php", client: 192.168.56.1, server: barry.dev, request: "GET /my_project_name/web/app_dev.php/ HTTP/1.1", host: "www.awesome.dev"

[01:40 PM]-[vagrant@local]-[/var/log/nginx] B
B$
```

I also read that a possible solution is editing the .htacces file, however I have no clue which one that should be then. I have seen one in the web directory, edited it and nothing happened, same goes for src directory and app directory.

Another possible solution is to set AcceptPathInfo "On". But then again I do not know where to find such, should be the virtual host accodring to one of the answers on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16236623/symfony-2-an-error-occurred-while-loading-the-web-debug-toolbar-404-not-foun) page.

And for those wondering, as you can see in the error log, I am using Nginx.

my_project_name/web/app_dev.php returns the toolbar error.

my_project_name/web/app_dev.php/controllername returns 404.

**Edit:** By making a new virtual machine and repeating the whole Symfony installation process and using Apache instead of Nginx somehow fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to edit the `.htaccess` file in the web directory. All files that are accessible through a browser are stored in the `web` directory. The other `.htaccess` files are merely a 'defence in depth' strategy that prevents directories being accidentally exposed.

This page covers the basic setup for Symfony2 with Apache2:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/configuration/web_server_configuration.html

Comment: Well replacing the .htacces file in the web folder with the code provided, does not help to fix the issue. I also replaced the configuration file with the configuration code but none has helped.

Comment: @Barrosy the Symfony/Apache2 setup detailed in the documentation works for 1000s of people (including me), so if it's not working for you, perhaps you have a typo somewhere or you have not followed all of the steps properly.

Comment: Okay thanks I will try to repeat installing all this and see if that'll work.